# I have been trying to compare all the contentid's of two api's in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have two api's which has the same contents but only the url changes, and I want to compare all the contents from both APIs using jmeter

I have used json extractor and extracted by using path as
$.. contentid given match no as -1 and checked the _All option

I have used beanshell assertion to compare the both APIs response, but one api has the all contentid's in random jumbled format so when I run the assertion I am getting error as assertion failed

For example response of one api has
{123,345,678,week,add}

And other api has
{add,123,678,week,345}

Can you help and possibly show how to compare them and get success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [JSONassert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) library, it allows comparing the JSON responses ignoring the attributes order and focusing only on content.

Also [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial).

More information: [Introduction to JSONassert](https://www.baeldung.com/jsonassert)